# Spring webflow & PrimeFaces expression language - bean method is interpreted as a property in websphere but not tomcat

Tags: jsf, tomcat, primefaces, websphere, spring-webflow

I have a WebFlow with an input:

```
<input name="allocationConfig" required="true"/>
```

which is then used to get the correct controller when searching for a list of stores in a PrimeFaces autocomplete input:

```
<p:autoComplete completeMethod="#{controllerLookup.get(allocationConfig).searchForStore}" ... />
```

`controllerLookup` is a Spring bean that returns a particular controller (which is also a Spring bean) when passed the `allocationConfig` from the webflow. The controller then returns a list of stores to display in the autocomplete input.

This works fine when I run it on Tomcat, but when it is deployed onto Websphere, I get this error:

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /WEB-INF/flows/manage-allocation/manage-allocation.xhtml @76,97 completeMethod="#{controllerLookup.get(allocationConfig).searchForStore}": Property 'get' not found on type com.web.controller.allocations.ControllerLookup
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.primefaces.component.autocomplete.AutoComplete.broadcast(AutoComplete.java:459)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processDecodes(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowLifecycle.invokePhase(FlowLifecycle.java:88)
    at org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowLifecycle.execute(FlowLifecycle.java:69)
    at org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfView.processUserEvent(JsfView.java:111)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.handleEvent(ViewState.java:225)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.resume(ViewState.java:195)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.resume(Flow.java:537)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:259)
    at org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:169)
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:228)
    at org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfFlowHandlerAdapter.handle(JsfFlowHandlerAdapter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:919)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:851)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1230)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
    at com.pcmsgroup.v21.web.config.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:46)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:964)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1104)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:914)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:287)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1865)
```

It seems that Websphere is wrongly interpreting `controllerLookup.get` as a property, whereas Tomcat correctly interprets it as a method.

Any ideas why Tomcat and Websphere are interpreting my EL differently? or how to fix it?

Comment: because they ship with a different EL implementation.

Comment: @M.Deinum That was my guess. I suppose what I really want is a workaround.

Comment: If you know they both ship with a different EL, then what would be the way to solve that.... I guess you should know that answer already.

Comment: What version of WebSphere and Java EE are you using? Method expressions are supported starting from Java EE 6  (EL 2.2).

Comment: @Gas Websphere 8 with JEE 6 and EL 2.2. So as you say, it should be able to handle method expressions.

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a workaround that seems to work so far.

I've changed the signature of the look-up method to be called `getController` without any parameters. Instead, it obtains the config object from Spring's flow scope:

```
public AllocationsController getController() {
    AllocationConfig config = (AllocationConfig) RequestContextHolder.getRequestContext().getFlowScope().get("allocationConfig");
    // Determine the concrete type of controller depending on the config, and return it.
}
```

and in the tag for the `autocomplete` input:

```
<p:autoComplete completeMethod="#{controllerLookup.controller.searchForStore}" ... />
```